# Put data from text file into HTML Android Webview

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, webview

Spent days searching and found no solution.

I'm not a programmer but I'm trying to create an android application that does a search only using a barcode reader.

An app that replaces those expensive check price machines. Just use a tablet and a barcode scanner, copy the file generated by the stock software (usually a plain text file with `.txt` extension) into a microSD card (not sure if I can send the file directly to the card via network).

This is the HTML page with javascript code (quite wrong and horrible but working as well).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
    <title>CONSULTA DE PRE&Ccedil;O</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="timestamp">
    <script>
        var TRange = null;
        function Procurar(str) {
            if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) < 4) 
                return;
            var Resultado;
            if (window.find) {
                Resultado=self.find(str);
                if (Resultado && self.getSelection && !self.getSelection().anchorNode) {
                    Resultado=self.find(str)
                }
                if (!Resultado) {
                    Resultado=self.find(str,0,1)
                    while (self.find(str,0,1)) 
                        continue
                }
            }
            else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {
                if (TRange!=null) {
                    TRange.collapse(false)
                    Resultado=TRange.findText(str)
                    if (Resultado)
                        TRange.select()
                }

                if (TRange==null || Resultado==0) {
                    TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange()
                    Resultado=TRange.findText(str)
                    if (Resultado) 
                        TRange.select()
                }
            }
            if (!Resultado) 
                alert ("PRODUTO SEM CADASTRO - PROCURE O VENDEDOR") 
            return;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color:blue;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        overflow-y: hidden
    }
    body,div,form,.campo {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0
    }
    *:focus {outline: none;}
    .cabeca, .barra {
        background-color:blue; 
        color:white;
        text-align:center
    }
    .resultado,#busca,.botao,.campo {
        background-color:yellow
    }
    #busca,.botao {
        color:yellow;border:0
    }
    .campo {
        margin-left:5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:15px;
        font-family:monospace;
        color:#000000;
        text-transform:uppercase
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 40px
    }
    h5 {
        font-size: 15px
    }
    h6 {
        font-size: 13px
    }
</style>
</head>

<body onload="document.getElementById('busca').focus();">
<div class="cabeca">
    <br>
    <h1><i>BUSCA PRE&Ccedil;O</i></h1>
    <h5><marquee behavior="alternate">PASSE O C&Oacute;DIGO DE BARRAS DO PRODUTO SOB O FEIXE DE LUZ</marquee></h5>
</div>
<div class="resultado">
    <form id="f1" action="" onsubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null &amp;&amp; this.t1.value!='') Procurar(this.t1.value);return false" name="f1">
        <input type="text" id="busca" name="t1" value="" size="20"> <input class="botao" type="submit" name="b1" value="Q">
    </form>

    <form action="">
        <textarea class="campo" name="mytextarea" cols="87" rows="3" readonly>

        <!-- TXT CONTENT HERE -->

        </textarea>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="barra">
    <h6>AGUARDE A CONSULTA ANTERIOR APAGAR ANTES DE REALIZAR OUTRA</h6>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my java:

```
package br.com.strabelli.qc.quantocusta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Tela extends Activity {

    WebView mwebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela);

        mwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mwebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        WebSettings webSettings = mwebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

        mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mwebview.canGoBack()) {
            mwebview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

The html file is correctly located in the asset directory, the application is running and the search works, but **the problem is that I need to inject the contents of the txt file (which should be located in sdcard) inside the  tag.**

The content of txt is like this

> 1000177935227|Figuras de Ontem e de Hoje|39,00|
>
> 1000177935333|Poeira Dourada|40,00|
>
> 1000177935371|Rui - Pequena Historia de Uma Grande Vida|15,00|
>
> 9788575183755|Dicionario Barsa da Li­ngua Portuguesa|60,00|
>
> 9788571644694|Uma Historia da Guerra|17,00|

I tried iframe and object but the search does not work inside this tags. I tried to find some solution with javascript but did not get anywhere.

It would be possible to generate the webview in pieces? Kind like this: `html (...)textarea + terminal.txt + /textarea (...) /html`

Thanks for any help, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do that is like following:

```
Load the html file from assets in a variable String html.
Load the .txt file from sdcard in a variable String text.
```

Do a text replace

```
html = html.replace("<!-- TXT CONTENT HERE -->", text);
```

Fially use the overloaded loadUrl to put the source html in the webview.

```
mwebview.loadUrl(html, ... other parameters...);
```

Or

```
mwebview.loadWithBaseUrl(html, ... other parameters ...);
```

Sorry at the moment no exact code parameters from memory.